# How to enable TLS on bolt protocol on Noe4j?

Tags: neo4j, cryptography, tls1.2, bolt

I have configured Neo4j to use encrypted connections bith with https in browser and bolt protocol. I have a valid certificate signed with a CA and the browser works fine accessing and runnign queries. Then problem comes with the cypher shell through bolt protocol. I'm getting this error:

```
 cypher-shell --encryption true -d database -a bolt://ip_address:7687 -u user -p password--debug

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
        ... 42 more
```

Both https and bolt use the same certificate and private key. The TLS configuration is:

```
# Bolt SSL configuration
dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.base_directory=certificates/bolt
dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.private_key=neo4j.key
dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.public_certificate=neo4j.crt

# Https SSL configuration                                                                                               dbms.ssl.policy.https.enabled=true
dbms.ssl.policy.https.base_directory=certificates/https
dbms.ssl.policy.https.private_key=neo4j.key
dbms.ssl.policy.https.public_certificate=neo4j.crt

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=REQUIRED
#dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687

# HTTP Connector. There can be zero or one HTTP connectors.                                                             dbms.connector.http.enabled=false
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7473
```

I'm using Neo4j 4.0.3 community version.

How can I solve thsi problem to use bolt protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
cypher-shell -u user -p password --debug -a host --encryption true
```

Or

```
cypher-shell -u user -p password --debug -a bolt+s://host
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.